# Magento2.1 - Deployment version issue

Tags: magento2, javascript, redis, static-content, deployment

In production mode , I tried to deployed the application.
Deployment was completed successfully but the changes in js file seems to be old. Static Signing is enabled in admin

I checked the pub/static/deployed_version.txt , but it shows previous deployment's timestamp.

In our application redis is also configured. I cleared the redis cache but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all the old files from

> ```
> pub/static/frontend
> pub/static/_requirejs
> var/generated/
> var/cache
> var/page_cache
> ```

Then run:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

(if you have multiple store then add those with space separated)

Comment: Is this a mandatory step to clear the pub folder in production.?

Comment: Without clearing the pub folder ,i checked this in local env , After flushing the Magento cache everything works as expected in Local. But not in production

Comment: Sometimes deployment files not override the existing one. On that case you need to clear the pub folder files and then run the process again.